# close bootstrap 5 modal before send ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to close the bootstrap 5 modal before sending ajax. For this, I used the following code, but Ajax runs first then the medal is closed.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        beforestart: function () {
            $("#freeModal").modal('hide');
        },
        url: '/url',
        })
```

And I don't want to use the following codes:

```
$("#myModal").modal('hide')
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/url',
            })
  });
```

Is there a way to close the medal first and then send Ajax?

Comment: As far as could research, it is `beforeSend`. Does `beforestart` throw any errors? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ .

Comment: There is no difference in both cases, Ajax is sent first, I want the modal to be closed first

Comment: Do you have the camelCase?